# How can I set a fixed row height for a range of rows?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that sets a certain row height for a range of rows, as shown below:

```
Sub Set_Row_Height()
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows("7:3000").RowHeight = 50
End Sub
```

This macro works as intended until I activate a selected cell within the range of rows. As a result, the row height changes to a smaller height of 15 or 20 pixels. Below is an example:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent the row height from changing when a cell is activated?

Comment: Perhaps put that code in a `Worksheet_Change()` event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protecting your Worksheet and settings `AllowFormattingRows:=False` will prevent a user from resizing the row.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="", AllowFormattingRows:=False, DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
    False, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
    AllowInsertingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True, _
    AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, AllowDeletingColumns:=True, _
    AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, _
    AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
```

Comment: Thank you @Thomas Inzina. This really helped.

Comment: So you just have to run that once, and it'll remain for the "life of the document"?  That's neat!